# search recursively using grep for any string of specific length without spaces

Tags: regex, bash, ubuntu, grep

I am trying to search for any string of say more than 200 characters without any space character in between.

I have tried multiple options, but nothing seems to work.

for example

`grep -r '.{200,}' /directory/sub-directory/`

`grep -r '[^\s.]{200,}' /directory/sub-directory/`

Comment: Did you try `grep -E '[^ ]{200,}' /directory/sub-directory/`?

Comment: There is no need to specify a range quantifier `{n,}`. In the event there is a 25 million non-space character sequence, better to just set a single like `{201}` for > 200.

Comment: Anyone down voting should at least give a hint how it is down voted. That will help in improving the Post if any thing is wanted. from my side I have tried to keep the question as clear as it should be. 1. It is not a possible duplicate I have searched thoroughly before posting. 2. I have mentioned what I have tried. 3. I have mentioned what is my expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{n,m}` specifier requires extended regexes (`grep -E`), and if you want anything but space, `[^ ]` should do. Also, "more than 200" is the same as "at least 201", so:

```
grep -rEe '[^ ]{201,}' path
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation `{n,m}` requires extended regexes. so you need to add flag `-E`

Comment: @lkkachu - can you give me a hint how I can add a include pattern in the above syntax as I am trying `grep -rEe --include=*.{php} '[^ ]{201,}' path`. but it's not working.

Comment: @Joshi, `--include="*.php"` should do? `grep` supports `*`, `?` and `[]` in include/exclude patterns (the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) mentions that). And the shell's brace expansion doesn't work with just one word inside the braces so the braces go to `grep`. I would quote the asterisk to prevent it being taken as a glob, though you probably don't have files called `--include=something` so you might get away with it this time. Use `set -x` to see what the commands actually do after all the expansions.

Answer (score 1):

`grep -o -E '\S{200,}' -r /directory`

- -o will only return the matching string instead of the whole line
- \S will match any non-whitespace

The rest you had already

Comment: Your solution is also good. but liked the explanation for extend regex by ikkachu